# WordPress.com: remove space between image and element (html)

Tags: images, html, wordpress

I'm trying to put a description below an image (WordPress.com site) and I want this description to be right below the image and with no gap between the elements (image and descrition)

I'm a photographer and I'm making a post with a few photos. It would be nice to have a little description below each photo.

I need this description to be below the photo and extends in width as the photo above it (800px). Also not to be a simple text but a line that has a background color and a text inside (I was thinking to use a table element with just one raw, but maybe there is a better way)

So the problem again, is that I can't find a way to stick this table right below the photo without any white space between the two elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the CELLPADDING and CELLSPACING attributes of TABLE, as in

> <table cellpadding="10">

Click on the keywords here for examples:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp

*Note that these are marked obsolete for HTML5.*

Comment: A little issue arised. I get an "<td" at the top of the image this is the code: <table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/449/19418882849_a81ba033f6_c.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #e8e8e8; text-align: center;">total so far: <strong>359km</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: `<td <img src ...` -> `<td> <img src ...`

Comment: Now maybe this is an issue with the theme I'm under (Big Brother) I already had tried what you indicated and the result is that the image gets out of the post area (I don't know if it's clear) The image becomes bigger and overlaps the side menu on the right.

Comment: Check the IMG tag at w3schools - there is an attribute to set the image width. The themes generally have image limits below 640px, some even 500px.

Comment: Thanks Hannu I'll check that out. Actually I solved the issue by removing the "<td" + </td> tagging the image url so thaturl just needed the "tr" tag.